# Bad Request (400): Why?

Tags: asp.net

Why do I get a 400 - bad request error using the following URL?  It is encoded using Server.UrlEncode.  The actual `path` query parameter is `C:\Development\Chase\Exports\ChaseExport-090312073930.zip`

```
http://localhost:50199/Common/Forms/Export_Stream.aspx%3fpath%3dC%3a%5CDevelopment%5CChase%5CExports%5CChaseExport-090312073930.zip
```

Comment: It will entirely depend on what Export_Stream is doing. That's in your code, which we can't see. Please post the code, and we're more likely to be able to answer the question.

Comment: It never gets to Export_Stream.  It's an HTTP server error, not a code error.  It means the URL is malformed, but I don't understand why, if I've UrlEncoded it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not urlencode the entire querystring, just the values, so URL should be

> http://localhost:50199/Common/Forms/Export_Stream.aspx?path=C%3a%5CDevelopment%5CChase%5CExports%5CChaseExport-090312073930.zip

Answer (score 4):

I've written an article with Stefan's help that explains how to do this:

[Experiments in Wackiness: Allowing percents, angle-brackets, and other naughty things in the ASP.NET/IIS Request URL](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Scott, that article looks great.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
http://localhost:50199/Common/Forms/Export_Stream.aspx?path=C%3a%5CDevelopment%5CChase%5CExports%5CChaseExport-090312073930.zip
```